# Docker nginx /var/www/html/public" failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm using ngnix via docker, when I'm trying to access to the specfied URL I have a "File not found" Using `docker-compose exec mycontainer sh` I read logs and saw `"/var/www/html/public" failed (13: Permission denied)` How can I give it right to read/execute file ?

My container was working and when I change right the problem appears
Thanks

Comment: It was working, you removed rights, and it returns "Permission denied"? What question is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolve by a simple `chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/public/`